# How can I control an iOS device's screen from a Mac?

Tags: ios, trackpad

Everything I've been able to find when Googling for this falls into one of these categories:

- it requires Jailbreaking;
- it's really [just a way to display the iOS device's screen with AirPlay](http://www.airserver.com/), and has *nothing* to do with controlling the screen;
- it's [a remote support service that charges up the wazoo](http://www.islonline.com/)

I don't particularly want to pay $20 just to get around the fact that Apple doesn't see fit to support trackpads and mice in iOS.  I can already connect my bluetooth keyboard to my iOS device, but I can't control the screen (as though I were touching the screen itself, without actually raising my arm up to monitor height, where my iOS device is mounted).

I do *not* need *remote* control—that is, control from a remote network—but if I can gain control of the screen using something designed for remote control, that's fine.

Comment: I *believe* that Apple has just very recently (within the last month or two) allowed remote control apps. Teamviewer has one (free for non commercial use) but it is a glorified remote screen capture utility. There is obviously a demand for remote control. Just wondering if some of the good stuff is still in developemnt.

Comment: @SteveChambers awesome!  Good to know.  Did you read this on developer.apple.com?  Or can you remember where you might have heard it?  I'd love to learn more.

Comment: I don't remember where I heard this, but not on developer.apple.com